# extracting some features from a dataframe column for KNN algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, knn

My question is about selecting and extracting some features from a dataframe column. Does that effect in the effectiveness of ML algorithms.
For example i'm doing analysis on "Chicago crime Dataset". It has a "Date Of Occurrence" column and it has data in this form: "2018-11-23 05:10:00". What i want to do is, i want to add some extra columns out of this for "year", "month", "weekday", "hour".

**Will that effect in efficiency of KNN Classifier algorithm.**

This is the link to dataset if you want to check which dataset I'm Talking about.

"https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding new features always benefits the model learning. It is always recommended to add individual new date features for date columns.

`day` `month` `day_of_week` `year` `is_it_weekend` `hour` `minute` `AM_PM` `season`